# Unable to create while/boolean loop

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I am a noob to java. i am trying to create a while loop that will prompt the user after each process; as to whether or not they wish to continue. my progress looks like this.

```
    String proString,answer;
    char t,f,x;
    boolean exitTime;
    exitTime = false;
    proString = " Would You Like To Continue? \n";
    while(!exitTime) {
        continue;
    }
    answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Would You Like To Continue? T/F ",HEADING,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    x = char.parseChar(answer);
```

I have tried the following as well to no avail...

```
    Prompt= JOptonPane.showInputDialog(null,proString,HEADING,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 
    input = char.parseChar(Prompt);
    if(input == "y") {
        break;
    }
    else if(input == "n") {
    }
    input = char.parseChar(Prompt);
    if(input != "y"||"n") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
    }
```

I guess my question comes down to should i use JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...) or JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...) or another method? please show me how you would do this.

Comment: it would be a lot easier to help you if the code in your question was formatted properly.

Comment: hence 'i am a noob.' how can i create a while loop with my variables?

Comment: Can you provide code that compiles? As is there are many parts of your code with incorrect syntax.

Comment: what data type is the variable input

Comment: i was using 'char input' because i was trying to get the question to return a char since i couldnt convert string to char...but this may be the wrong thinking...

Comment: `while(!exitTime) { continue;  }` creates an infinite loop that does nothing.  You never reach the code for your dialogue box...

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to use a do-while loop:

```
//assume user does not want to continue.
boolean continue = false;
do
{
//process whatever you want

//ask the user
Prompt= JOptonPane.showInputDialog(null,proString,HEADING,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
input = char.parseChar(Prompt);
//wait until you get a valid input
while(input != "y"||"n")
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input", "Error",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
Prompt= JOptonPane.showInputDialog(null,proString,HEADING,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 
input = char.parseChar(Prompt);
}
//if user wants to continue, change your flag to true
if(input == "y") {
    continue = true;
}
//otherwise make it false
else if(input == "n") {
    continue = false;
}
while(continue); //if continue is true loop back
```

I haven't tested it but it should explain you the logic.